# Change system Java

Tags: java, batch-file, cmd

I have 3 java in my system 1.6, 1.7 and java 8. 
I set my **JAVA_HOME** and path to 1.7, but when I run **java -version** using cmd administrator mode it return me 8.
Could anyone please tell me from where cmd pick java, and how i can change it to another version.

**Updated:** I already set java 7/bin in path variable

Comment: Try to put the path to java first in your %PATH%

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When we run cmd as an administrator then it pick java.exe which is already available under C:/user/windows32 folder.

To resolve this issue, instead of appending my java at the end of the path, append in the starting of the path vaiable.

So here is the code used in cmd if run as administrator

```
set path=%JAVA_HOME%/bin;%path%;
java -version
```

Answer (score 0):

Start your cmd shell and type `echo %PATH%`.

OS would inspect listed directories and the first one that has `java` binary will be the one being used.

To change it - the `PATH` variable is set based on the settings in `Control Panel` -> `System` -> `Advanced System Settings` -> `Environment Variables`. You'd need to start a new cmd session to see updated changes.

Comment: @Gorgi thanks for the answer. I already set my environment variable. But got my answer from another site.